# can any jquery / css3 plugins be embedded in ionic project

Tags: jquery, angularjs, css, cordova, ionic-framework

I have just started to learn ionic and i have the question to which i still couldn' find an exact answer about whether all the bunch of common nice jquery and CSS3 plugins ([here](http://designmodo.com/css-jquery-plugins-coding/) are some examples) used for the web can be embedded in ionic projects and if yes how (is it by developing cordova plugins or by making custom angular.js directives or by another way) and i want to know if using such as non native components will have a significant effect on the application performance. I'm really one of those who which take profit of nice web plugins on a mobile application and that's why this question is important for me.

Comment: Yes..using directives although there are also lots of angular modules around and you shouldn't focus on using jQuery as a first resort. Also angular itself has ability to simplify many things that might have been done by using a plugin  in the past